# How to generate -5V to +5V from 0-10V input with direction signal

Tags: operational-amplifier, offset

I have a motor controller that requires +5V to -5V for speed and direction. The trouble is, the output from the driver is 0-10V speed with a TTL 5V direction control. 0V in one direction and 5V in the other with the 0-10V being the speed.

Is it possible to use op-amps to convert this to -5V to +5V? I can easily convert the 0-10V into 0V to +5V using an op-amp but I can't figure out how to use the direction signal to invert this. I tried using an AD8170ARZ MUX IC with 0 to +5V on one input and 0 to -5V on the other but the output won't swing above or below +-3.26V and I've not found another suitable 8-pin SOIC device to do the same.

My supplies available are +-12V and +-5V if that helps.

Based on the request below, the following logic table may help:

```
Speed (Volts)   Direction    Output (volts)

0                   0        0
5                   0        -2.5
10                  0        -5.0
0                   1        0
5                   1        +2.5
10                  1        +5.0
```

Comment: It's still not clear to me exactly what mapping you want. Please add a table or graph to your question. I think the motor controller has a single line which requires 0 V to be stationary, with +5 V full forward, -5 V full reverse. The driver is 0 V stationary, with 10 V full speed, direction indicated by the logic direction control.

Comment: @Neil_UK, I've added a logic table. Your assumptions are correct.

Comment: [Rohat Kılıç's HINT](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/645238/274544) is spot-on: the AD8170ARZ's output is by no means rail-to-rail.

Answer (score 2):

If you can live with the direction control being inverted (so a logic 1 produces a negative output), then this should do the job:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqwz3E.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: I can use an additional amp to invert the output to get the correct logic. Thanks for the circuit.

Comment: @DaveMcLaughlin - or a logic inverter (or additional transistor configured as such) to invert the direction control input.

Answer (score 1):

```
Speed (Volts)   Direction    Output (volts)

 0                  0         0
 5                  0        -2.5
10                  0        -5.0
 0                  1         0
 5                  1        +2.5
10                  1        +5.0
```

So it's basically, inverted or the non-inverted copy of half the input voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyYEej.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The top section is an inverter, the bottom section is a buffer. With the analog SPDT switch one of the section will be directed to the output buffer.

The key part here is the analog switch. There are numerous analog SPDT switches that can handle negative voltages. I'm leaving the component selection to you.

HINT: If the analog switch you found is not able to handle ±5V then you can modify the top and bottom sections to generate, say, ±Vin/4 then replace the output buffer with x2 non-inverting amplifier.

Comment: OA2's input is held at ground by the virtual ground action of OA1, which also makes R2 superfluous! Try feeding the two amplifiers independently from Vin.

Comment: @Neil_UK oh yeah. Now I caught the point. Thanks.

Comment: `why would I connect the inverter input to buffer output?` Old school analogue design habit: make input 1MOhm unless there is a reason not to.

Comment: I already had the amp circuit to generate the 2 outputs as you have but I had issues finding a small SMD part for the analog switch which would work up to the -5V and +5V rails. Finding stock was another issue.